# xsl stylesheet for generating word documents from Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ms-word

I was wondering if there is any Java API which allows to generate Word document similarly Apache FOP does.
With FOP, it is possible to specify a style sheet which defines the layout of the page in which the data (stored in an xml file) are printed.
The Transformer object within FOP library is in charge of that.

Is there any equivalent API for word document?

Answer (score 1):

With FOP, you can try [XML to RTF](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/rtflib.html), which Word accepts.

[From their webpage, XMLmind XSL-FO Converter](http://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/) apparently generates:

- RTF (can be opened in Word 2000+),
- WordprocessingML (can be opened inWord 2003+),
- Office Open XML (.docx, can be opened in Word 2007+),

Putting FO to one side, here are 2 different approaches:

The first would be to write an XSLT to convert your XML to Flat OPC XML. Most parts in the Flat OPC XML would simply be copied there by your XSLT.  (Generate that template content in Word, using "save as XML").  You'll be focusing mainly on populating the document.xml part.  Word can open a Flat OPC XML file, or you can use docx4j (a project I work on) to convert Flat OPC XML to docx.

The second would be to use the [docx4j Flying Saucer fork](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML) to convert your XML + CSS to docx content.  See the [code samples](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples).  You may need to customise it a bit; one way of feeding it CSS is [this file](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/resources/XhtmlNamespaceHandler.css). This actually ought to work pretty well; there is stuff there for mapping class attributes to Word styles, so if you could adorn your XML with class attributes, you could get even better results.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your input is an XML document, or at least a CSV file.

1) Create an XSLT stylesheet to transform your input into the Word document format. The result will be a file we will call `content.xml`. You can apply the stylesheet to the input from Java.

2) Create a MS Word shell and put the `content.xml` into the shell. There are tools within [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to do this.

I may have taken your question too literally. You might also be able to generate the document using Apache POI API. Also, if your MS Word document doesn't have tables, you can use Apache FOP to generate an RTF document, which can then be easily translated to a `.docx` file.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) provides Java APIs for reading and writing Microsoft Excel, Word, and PowerPoint files.

You can checkout POI's Javadocs [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html).